# NullPointerException maven-jaxb2-plugin WSDL

Tags: java, spring, web-services, maven, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm new to consuming webservices from spring aplications, so I was working in the tutorial found at spring guides website, and it works perfectly, so, since I need to consume the webservice defined by [this wsdl](https://201.175.25.245/ventanilla-ws-pedimentos/ListarPedimentosService?wsdl) I tried to simply change the url in the plugin configuration, so, in my pom.xml file, instead of

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
        <generatePackage>hello.wsdl</generatePackage>
        <schemas>
            <schema>
                <url>http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl</url>
            </schema>
        </schemas>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

which is the exact code from the tutorial, I got

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
        <generatePackage>listarPedimentos.wsdl</generatePackage>
        <specVersion>2.1.5</specVersion>
        <schemas>
            <schema>
                <url>https://201.175.25.245/ventanilla-ws-pedimentos/ListarPedimentosService?wsdl</url>
            </schema>
        </schemas>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

while doing some research, I found that it was posible that it could be a problem caused by the jaxb2 version, so I changed it to 0.13.1, later I found that it could be due the webservice being created by  JAX-WS 2.1.5. and found that it could be solved by adding
    2.1.5
to the configuration section of the plugin declaration, but its not working, and I'm still getting the same error

```
Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate failed. (org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate:default:generate-sources)
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate failed.
    at   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadWSDL(ModelLoader.java:408)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:170)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:119)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.loadModel(XJC22Mojo.java:50)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:40)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:28)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:505)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 31 more
```

I'using Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

my complete pom.xml file is https://codeshare.io/7ZEas

Comment: Try with http:// URL. You are currently using https:// in configuration schema url.

Answer (score 0):

changing from https to http worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried it and it worked! thanks I really appreciate it!